# What should we do with questions that ask about cracked versions of free games?

Tags: discussion, allowed-answers, game-piracy

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/345469/172501) is asking for certain maps on [counter-strike-global-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-global-offensive). The OP mentions the version of the game is a cracked one.

I flagged the question as off-topic based on illegal content or piracy. However, I also posted an answer stating the we (Arqade) do not discuss illegal content or piracy, but mentioned that the user can just get a free Steam account and access the game for free.

I believe my answer was helpful, but I didn't directly answer the question, **and** I posted an answer on a question that is off-topic for Arqade. Is this a bad thing to do?

**Edit:** I just noticed that the OP mentioned limited bandwidth for downloads, so even then my answer was a bad one. If that wasn't a problem, would the correct course of action close the question as off-topic or answer, pointing the user to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a bad thing to do?

It is not recommended to post an answer to a question that is off-topic; even more so if it does not even answer the question. If the question is off-topic, it will eventually (which that question is now currently) be deleted, so posting an answer is not necessary.

In this case, the correct course of action would have been to flag the question appropriately and leave it to the community. If you choose to do so in the future, post the information as a comment.